# How to extract the output of each gates of a trained LSTM model (Keras - TF backend)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, keras-layer

I am working with a trained LSTM model. I want to extract the output of each gates at prediction, and where the input is a single sequence. In `recurrent.py` (from keras package), that would be given by:

```
i = self.recurrent_activation(x_i + K.dot(h_tm1_i, 
self.recurrent_kernel_i))
f = self.recurrent_activation(x_f + K.dot(h_tm1_f, 
self.recurrent_kernel_f))
c = f * c_tm1 + i * self.activation(x_c + K.dot(h_tm1_c,
self.recurrent_kernel_c))
```

I'm unable to extract `i`, `c`, `f`, `o` matrices as can be done for the weights and biases:

```
for layer in model.layers:
  if "lstm" in str(layer).lower():
    kernel_i = K.get_value(layer.kernel_i)
    kernel_f = K.get_value(layer.kernel_f)
....
```

EDITED

> I tried to compute the activations using for example:
>
> ```
> x_i = K.dot(inputs_i, kernel_i)
> ```
>
> but then, it outputs the following error: `'numpy.ndarray' object has
>   no attribute 'get_shape'`

That's wrong, because both `inputs_i` and `kernel_i` are numpy arrays.
The correct way is:

```
x_i = np.dot(inputs_i, kernel_i)
```

and then add bias: `x_i = x_i + bias_i`

Still following `recurrent.py`, the next step is to get the output of the input gate `i` for example:

```
i = self.recurrent_activation(x_i + K.dot(h_tm1_i, 
    self.recurrent_kernel_i))
```

Need to 1st convert `x_i` into a tensor and then get the recurrent_activation from the layer object:

```
x_i_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(x_i, np.float32) 
i = layer_lstm.recurrent_activation(x_i_tensor + K.dot(h_tm1_i,
    layer_lstm.recurrent_kernel_i))
```

**So, now the question is how to access the hidden state `h_tm1_i`**?
I'd appreciate some suggestions. Thanks

Comment: Which Keras version are you using?

Comment: Keras version 2.0.3